# Elasticsearch query aggregation only terms with a specific pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I have made this query in elasticsearch:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tokens.keyword",
        "size": 50,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns me the 50 most present tokens in my documents.

I want the 50 most present token that start with the specific characters "$". 
How can I transform my query to get what I want with the best performances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work !

```
{ 
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "tokens.keyword": "$*" 
    }
  }, 
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  }, 
  "aggs": { 
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tokens.keyword",
        "size": 50,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[wildcard] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 7,
        "col": 5